# Calling wordpress menu outside ignores custom menu item

Tags: menus, outside-wordpress

I have a wordpress website and I want to use wordpress menu outside the installation.

So I created a file called nav.php and put the following code

```
  include( '../wp-load.php' ); 
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary','menu_id' =>   'cartel' ) );
```

In the header on another website,

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/nav.php') ?>
```

This ignores the menu item having custom link created in the WordPress menu. Please help. for example (SHOP [/shop/])

Answer (score 0):

You can not use WordPress functions outside your wordpress dir (wordpress core). 
Wordpress is a framework and you need to create pages based on the guidelines set by WP community.

You need to create a proper WP page and than maybe use it on the other domain with iframe.